# Python - WebSocket Access protection

Tags: python, multithreading, websocket, password-protection

I would like to know how to protect a WebSocket from unauthorized access by adding some kind of credentials check.

Based on code found on the internet I have put together this code that uses threads to open multiple client connections.
However, right now, anyone which knows the IP and the port number can access and send text to the python script on the raspberry. (I need to access the WebSocket from outside my Wifi so I will need to port-forward to allow Internet access)

One solution I guess would be to add a simple String check that could verify if the first text written by the client is the same as a "password" then the whole functionality of the script is allowed and if not the connection is rejected.

But, **how is this really done in a more proffesional way without overcomplicating it?**

My objective is to connect to this WebSocket via terminal by typing commands, and also via HTML5 (have not worked on this yet).

```
import socket               # Websocket 
import sys                  # 
from _thread import *       # Used for multi-threading      The thread module has been renamed to _thread in Python 3.
import urllib.request       # Used to make requests
import urllib
import time                 # Used to create delays


import functions
t thread as _thread


# ******* WEBSOCKET VARIABLES *******
numberClients = 0
host = ''
PORT = xxxx
# ******* WEBSOCKET VARIABLES *******




# ************************** FUNCTIONS **************************
def threaded_client(conn,address):      # receive as parameters, the connection object (conn), and the address object that contains the ip and port
    global numberClients
    conn.send(str.encode('Welcome, type your info\n'))  # data should be bytes
    numberClients = numberClients + 1

    #print ("direccion" + str(address[0]))

    #           CHECK USER USING PASSWORD OR SOMETHING
    #           CHECK USER USING PASSWORD OR SOMETHING
    #           CHECK USER USING PASSWORD OR SOMETHING
    #           CHECK USER USING PASSWORD OR SOMETHING
    #           CHECK USER USING PASSWORD OR SOMETHING
    #           CHECK USER USING PASSWORD OR SOMETHING
    while True:
        data = conn.recv(2048)
        reply = "" + 'Server output: '+ data.decode('utf-8').rstrip() + "\n"
        print(str(address[0]) + " - Clients(" + str(numberClients) + ") -> Data received: >" + data.decode('utf-8').rstrip() + "<")
        if not data:
            print("no data")
            break
        conn.sendall(str.encode(reply))     # data should be bytes
    print("Thread connection closed by client: " + address[0])
    conn.close()
    numberClients = numberClients - 1
# ************************** FUNCTIONS **************************




# ************************** SETUP **************************
print ("\n----------- Starting Websocket Python Program -----------\n")

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)   # "s" here is being returned a "socket descriptor" by socket.socket.
print(s)

# we are simply attempeting to bind a socket locally, on PORT xxxx.
try:
    s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)         # reuse the port number (in case we just got an error and port was not freed)
    s.bind((host, PORT))                                            # server side - take IN connections
    print ("Server started on port " + str(PORT))
except socket.error as e:
    print(str(e))
    print('Bind failed. Error Code : ' + str(msg[0]) + ' Message ' + msg[1])
    #sys.exit()
print('Socket bind complete')

s.listen(5)     # the "5" stands for how many incoming connections we're willing to queue before denying any more.

print('Waiting for a connection.')
# ************************** SETUP **************************





# ************************** MAIN LOOP **************************
while True:
    conn, addr = s.accept()         # code will stop here whilst waiting for a new connection. Old connections will be running in the threads
    print('Connected to: '+addr[0]+':'+str(addr[1]))

    start_new_thread(threaded_client,(conn,addr))   
# ************************** MAIN LOOP **************************
```

Comment: Have you of thought of using python decorators?

Comment: I am pretty new to python so I know anything about python decorators. I will read this (http://simeonfranklin.com/blog/2012/jul/1/python-decorators-in-12-steps/) to see if it helps. Could you elaborate? The first thing I read is decorators are complex and I was looking for something as easy as possible to implement. thanks

Comment: Can you please check this link. this link is better . https://pythonconquerstheuniverse.wordpress.com/2009/08/06/introduction-to-python-decorators-part-1/

Comment: Thank you but I don't understand how to protect the web socket from unwanted clients. Any help anyone?

Comment: What I meant was to add a decorator @Authenticated which will check the credentials and pwd, and if authenticated will allow. You can handle if it is not authenticated in the same decorator. Write all the functionality in the function and call the decorator before the function.